# Synchronize multiple timeseries

Tags: matlab, time-series

The synchronize() function only takes 2 timeseries arguments. What is the standard procedure if you need to sync more than 2 timeseries? I tried to sync (one of the outputs of syncing timeseries 1 and 2) with timeseries 3, but the results are not synced (e.g. the same length) (as shown below) because it simply has to do with the range of the time data:

```
% Create data set 1
t1 = rand(10,1);
data1=rand(10,1);
ts1=timeseries(data1,t1);

% Create data set 2
t2 = rand(8,1);
data2=rand(length(t2), 1);
ts2=timeseries(data2,t2);

% Create data set 3
t3 = rand(5,1);
data3=rand(length(t3), 1);
ts3=timeseries(data3,t3);

% Sync 1 and 2
[uniform_ts12_1 uniform_ts12_2] = synchronize(ts1,ts2,'Uniform','Interval',.1);

% Sync 3 to one of the results of the (sync of 1 and 2)
[uniform_ts13_1 uniform_ts13_3] = synchronize(uniform_ts12_1,ts3,'Uniform','Interval',.1);

disp('New sizes:')
length(uniform_ts12_1.Data)
length(uniform_ts12_2.Data)
length(uniform_ts13_1.Data)
length(uniform_ts13_3.Data)
```

Can anyone suggest how to sync 3 timeseries so they all have identical time data at the end of the day?

EDIT:

The problem is that the lengths of uniform_ts12_1, uniform_ts12_2, uniform_ts13_1, and length(uniform_ts13 are not the same. It syncs 2 with 1, but then if 3 is outside (or well inside) the bounds of 2, it syncs them to the smaller one (3), which is now not the same length as the sync between 1 and 2.

Comment: In what way does your current approach fail?

Comment: The lengths of uniform_ts12_1, uniform_ts12_2, uniform_ts13_1, and length(uniform_ts13 are not the same. It syncs 2 with 1, but then if 3 is outside (or well inside) the bounds of 2, it syncs them to the smaller one (3), which is now not the same length as the sync between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to synchronize all possible pairs together, using the synchronized timeseries each time. I think it is simplifying if you go ahead and modify the timeseries' you are synchronizing in place so you do not have to keep track of which values to pass in. Just keep 3 timeseries around and as they each are modified you only need to permute them all so that all pairs of timeseries have been synced together:

```
>> [ts1 ts2] = synchronize(ts1, ts2, 'Union');
>> [ts1 ts3] = synchronize(ts1, ts3, 'Union');
>> [ts2 ts3] = synchronize(ts2, ts3, 'Union');
>> all(ts1.Time == ts2.Time)

ans =

     1

>> all(ts1.Time == ts3.Time)

ans =

 1

>>
```

Hope that helps!